# How to find the optimal value for mongo.options.connectionsPerHost

Tags: mongodb, grails, gorm-mongodb

Currently I am using Grails and I am running several servers connecting to a single mongo server.

```
options {
            autoConnectRetry = true
            connectTimeout = 3000
            connectionsPerHost = 100
            socketTimeout = 60000
            threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 10
            maxAutoConnectRetryTime=5
            maxWaitTime=120000
        }
```

Unfortunately, when I run 50 servers, total number of connections goes up by 5k. After a bit of research I found that this was a simple config in the DataSource.groovy

I am sure that my programs do not need 100 mongo connections.
But I am unsure what value should I set this to.

I have 2 doubts.
First, how to determine the optimal value for the connectionsPerHost.
Second, whether all these 100 connections are created once and then pooled?

Comment: Just a comment for clarity. On the second, no driver creates connections up to the maximum on initialize. Without diving into the driver code right now, the general consenus is 10 connections in the pool on init, and mostly where the asynchronous support is provided at least in the base driver level. As for *"What is optmimal(sic)?"* then it depends on your own application and usage patterns. Higher levels of evented or threaded transactions usually tend towards a higher pool. Concurrent threads/evented actions also being a factor. What can your app take in the environment, before clustering?

Comment: The other thing to note here is that even with multiple application servers, there is still a "connection cost" to the server itself ( of which you say you "only have one" ["highlander style"] ), this it something like 2MB per connection from memory without looking things up. So there is a certain point where this "slows things down", and considerably considering the resources used for a connection are eating into what MongoDB will otherwise use for purposes such as keeping the "working set" of a collection in memory. When hitting these limits, it's time to look towards sharding.

Comment: Thanks a lot Blakes. This really helped. One doubt, though. As you said "the general consenus is 10 connections in the pool on init". Does that mean connectionsPerHost = 100 is the max number of connections per host? I understood it to be the fixed number of connections per host.